# Linking to Google Play Store from Dialog in lower API

Tags: android

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the responses. API 21 was an emulator where the app store is not available, hence the error.

**ORIGINAL:**

I am linking to Google Play Store from an `AlertDialog` in my app. It works fine in API 24, but crashes in API 21 with

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android.example pkg=com.android.vending }
```

I call a helper function to show the `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` in `MainActivity`:

```
SharedHelper.showUpdateAlertDialog(this, "title", "message");
```

`SharedHelper` class:

```
public static void showUpdateAlertDialog(final Context context, String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle(title);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android.example"));
            intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
            context.startActivity(intent);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();
}
```

If I add

```
intent.setClass(context, context.getClass());
```

the app won't crash anymore, but nothing happens upon click in either API 24 or API 21 (although `onClick` is triggered, I checked).

I tried changing `AndroidManifest.xml`. It looks like this at the moment for MainActivity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    try
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException exception)
    {
        // app store is not available
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine in API 24, crashes in API 21 with "No Activity found to handle Intent"

Comment: Updated. Please do something in the try-catch block when app store like google play is not installed on your phone.

Comment: I think you are right and I'm using an emulator where the App store is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
 try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                        + appPackageName)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google" +
                        ".com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
            }
```